# Short story about a wizard who duels his darker half

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

There was a shortish story I read in middle school that was about a young boy who wanted to be a wizard.

My memory is spotty, but I remember him training with someone who kept having him look at plants and herbs. If I recall correctly he got fed up and looked at his mentors spell book and cast some very difficult spell that unleashed "a monster" on the world that would dominate his destiny.

His mentor saved him and nursed him back to health, gave him a staff and sent him to some wizard school that he thought the young kid would prefer to learn at.

More stuff happens... But I remember in the end he had to fight a dark version of himself.

Had the definite feel of a Bildungsroman.

Comment: Hi!  Welcome to SF&F.  This is  very nice description, but a few more details might help us.  In what language did you read it?  Was it in a magazine or an anthology?  When did you read it (we don't know when you were in middle school!)  Was the story old or new then?

Comment: From the title I thought it must be Lord of the Rings! ;-)

Answer (score 46):

This sounds like a slightly mixed up version of Ursula K. Le Guin's [*"A Wizard Of Earthsea"*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Wizard_of_Earthsea).

The boy summons a dark creature, which is banished by his teacher; who then sends him to the magic academy. He gets into a spell contest with a classmate, and summons the creature again, but this time it physically manifests. Most of the book is him trying to banish the creature.

Comment: Unquestionably, this is it.  "Someone who kept having him look at plants and herbs" sounds like a very apt description of Ogion the Silent from Sparrowhawk's point of view.

Comment: Note that *A Wizard of Earthsea* isn't a "shortish story" but a full-length novel of about 200 pages.

Comment: @NateEldredge Which is good. Identification Q's always have 1 detail which is completely wrong.

Comment: Also as far as I remember Ogion (mentor in this case) does not save Ged (main character) nor gives him a staff and send him back to wizard school again.

Comment: @NateEldredge Weren't there a couple lesser-known short stories in the Earthsea universe that were published earlier?  Not sure if they had the same plot elements though...

Comment: @DarrelHoffman: There were "The Word of Unbinding" and "The Rule of Names" but they don't fit this description at all.

Comment: I Was about to question exactly that, with the caveat that Wizard of Earthsea could never be considered a "short story". What did I miss?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin My kids would definitely consider 200 pages "short"

Comment: On top of Wizard of Earthsea being short by modern adult novel standards (though fairly normal for elementary/middle school novels), another possibility for remembering it as a short story is that the OP may have been first introduced to the book through an excerpt in [Childcraft](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Childcraft) vol. 3, from 1989. That only included the first chapter (which doesn't have most of the material the OP mentions), but if they read the excerpt, then tracked down the novel, they might have conflated their first encounter in short story form with the novel they read later.

Comment: Good grief! Where do you people get these ideas? Kevin? ShadowRanger? Wizard of Earthsea has for decades been recognised as a full-length novel.

Failing that, anything like 200 pages would make it at worst a novella.

"Short stories" often run to 20-odd pages. What's your basis for comparison?

If you suggest "modern adult novel standards" say anything about length, where is that written and what, exactly, do those writings say?

If you suggest "elementary/middle-school novel standards"  should say anything different about length, where is that written?

I suggest you read more!

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin: For the Fantasy genre, it's on the short end. It's 56K words. [According to at least one source](https://www.tckpublishing.com/how-long-should-a-book-be/) (all numbers from same source), novellas end, and novels begins, at 40K words. But fantasy, sci-fi and literary novels all tend to be (much) longer than that. 56K sits comfortably in the low-end of YA and middle grade fiction lengths though. If it were a murder mystery or the like, Wizard of Earthsea's word count would be a reasonable adult novel length, but it's short by adult fantasy standards, that's all.

Comment: On physical size, I own some old paperbacks of the original Earthsea trilogy. They seem even shorter in that form; the books are *tiny* relative to basically every other novel I own (and I own a lot; I'm at the point of considering expanding my house at least in part to make room for more bookshelves); my Elmore Leonards are the closest to it (thus the crime novel comparison). I suspect this is at least partially about using smaller fonts and narrower line spacing, but it could contribute to the feeling that they're "short" (especially when you're talking about a memory from decades ago).

Comment: @ShadowRanger Expelliarmus on your cherry-picking. A longer squint at the TCK link might bring back to mind "It’s… one of those questions for which there’s no right answer…" or "Short stories are often defined as any story under 7,500 words…" and that page-count depends on page- and type-size.

Try asking a book-store owner…